# ActiveRecords search with two params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table named measurements and a model named measure.
I have a method one_day_measurements_index in the controller.
Here is the code:

```
      def one_day_measurements_index
        @record = Measurement.last
        if @record.blank?
          @scheduled_on = Date.today
        else
          @scheduled_on = params[:date] || @record.scheduled_on
        end

        if @record.blank?
          flash[:danger] = "No Measurements Calculated."
          redirect_to measurements_path
        else
          if @scheduled_on.blank?
            @scheduled_on = params[:date] || Date.today
          end
          @page = params[:page] || 1
          @per_page = params[:per_page] || WillPaginate.per_page
          if params[:search]
            @measurements = Measurement
            .where("scheduled_on = '#{@scheduled_on}'")
            .search(params[:search])
            .paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
            .order("get_inst_status(instrument_id), instrument_id")
          else
            @measurements = Measurement
            .where("scheduled_on = '#{@scheduled_on}'")
            .paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
            .order("get_inst_status(instrument_id), instrument_id")
          end
        end

        measurements_hash @measurements
      end
```

I can use search entering a string, the search method in the model is:

```
    private
    def self.search(search)
      where('
            upper(reading_type) like upper(:search)
          or upper(daily_sequence) like upper(:search)
            or upper(reading_frequency) like upper(:search)
            or upper(reading_period) like upper(:search)
            or upper(reading_period) like upper(:search)
            or upper(measured_by) like upper(:search)
            or upper(measured_with) like upper(:search)
            or upper(crew) like upper(:search)
            or get_inst_id(instrument_id) like upper(:search)
            or get_inst_group_id(instrument_id) like upper(:search)
          or upper(get_inst_status(instrument_id)) like upper(:search)
          ', search: "%#{search}%")
    end
```

In the one_day_measurements_index.html.erb I am using this search tag:

```
<%= form_tag one_day_measurements_index_path, :method => 'get', class: "search" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search], options = {:placeholder => "Search", :class => "search_field"})%>
<% end %>
```

And the path in the routes.rb is:

```
  match 'one_day_measurements_index',   to: 'measurements#one_day_measurements_index',  via: 'get'
```

Here is the problem.
The page rendered show on top of the rows the tag for search lets say by a string.
Below the listed rows I have a tag to select with date picker the date since I want to see only the records for that date.
Here it is:

```
<%= form_tag one_day_measurements_index_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :date, params[:date], options = {:placeholder => "Date (yyyy-mm-dd)", :class => 'datetimepicker'} %>
  <%= submit_tag "Show Measurements for Date", class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

So in a nutshell I have to search tags for a string lets say an instrument type and the date for which I want to see those records. Practically I want to see all the records for instruments of type MPBX on the date of '2015-02-25'. The entire table has records for two more dates after that, '2015-02-26' and '2015-02-27'.

When I am entering the date '2015-02-25' I can see only the records from that date, which is correct. But when I am entering after that in the other search tag the string MPBX, the rendered page shown is for the date of '2015-02-27', the last date recorded in the table. Also no rows are shown since MPBX existed only on the date of '2015-02-25'.

Don't know how to solve this. Any clues?

Comment: why not just build your entire "search" using the **.where** functionality of Rails?

Comment: Because search method in the model is used as it is in other index methods in the same controller, the general index method for the entire table and another one for a week named one_week_measurements_index.

Comment: OK, I eliminated the search method used and I change the .where as you suggested, the result is the same as before, here is the new code:

Comment: ``` if params[:search]
        @search = params[:search]
        @measurements = Measurement
        .where("scheduled_on = '#{@scheduled_on}'
          and (upper(reading_type) like upper('#{@search}')
          or upper(daily_sequence) like upper('#{@search}')
          or upper(reading_frequency) like upper('#{@search}')
...
          )")
        .paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
        .order("get_inst_status(instrument_id), instrument_id")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

based on your comments, I've first of all refactored your controller code into a bit more readable structure. I hope I've not broken your logic by doing this:

```
def one_day_measurements_index
    unless Measurements.last
        @scheduled_on = Date.Today
        flash[:danger] = “No Measurements Calculated.”
        render(action:  "one_day_measurements_index") and return
    end

    @scheduled_on = params[:date] || @record.scheduled_on
    @page = params[:page] || 1
    @per_page = params[:per_page] || WillPaginate.per_page

    # Now we actually search on date first. 
    @measurements = Measurement.where("scheduled_on = '#{@scheduled_on}'")

    # if the search string is provided, we perform a narrower search on
    # the records of the matching date.
    if params[:search]
        @measurements.where('
            upper(reading_type) like upper(:search)
          or upper(daily_sequence) like upper(:search)
            or upper(reading_frequency) like upper(:search)
            or upper(reading_period) like upper(:search)
            or upper(reading_period) like upper(:search)
            or upper(measured_by) like upper(:search)
            or upper(measured_with) like upper(:search)
            or upper(crew) like upper(:search)
            or get_inst_id(instrument_id) like upper(:search)
            or get_inst_group_id(instrument_id) like upper(:search)
          or upper(get_inst_status(instrument_id)) like upper(:search)
          ', search: “%#{params[:search]}%”)
    end

    # We finish by paginating and ordering our result.   
    @measurements.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
    @measurements.order("get_inst_status(instrument_id), instrument_id")
end
```

If I made no mistakes, the code should do the following:

- Takes the last Measurement in your table.
- If not found, then we set the @scheduled_on and show the page.
- If the date is provided, we set that as criteria + pagination values
- then we actually search using our criteria

I think the problem lies in that you performed a **redirect_to** which does not store the variables you have defined, basically resetting your query every time.

Let me know how this turns out, and I can make edits based on your feedback.

**EDIT**
I'm not 100% sure if this approach will, since I do not know enough about your application. It could potentially be that this results in a not working page based on the information in your DB, but unfortunately I do not have enough info to catch all cases.

Comment: OK, here is what I did: a) I replaced my one day index method with yours. b) I corrected couple more things to get over errors, i.e. I replaced unless Measurements.last with unless Measurement.last c) I added @measurements = ... where was missing to avoid other errors. The result is the same. When MPBX is introduced in the search the page rendered is for 2015-02-27 and empty since MPBX-es are for that 25th only. I promoted everything to prod which is having de same data as dev. You can see the results from database using http://instrumon.herokuapp.com after sign up and going to Measurements.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I added this to the where clause: if params[:search]
        @measurements = @measurements.where("
          scheduled_on = '#{@scheduled_on}' and 
          (
          upper(reading_type) like upper(:search)
 ....

Comment: No difference in the response.